# Convert special characters into decimal equivalents in java

Tags: java

Is there a java library to convert special characters into decimal equivalent?

example:
input: "©™®"
output: "& #169; & #8482; & #174;"(space after & is only for question purpose, if typed without a space decimal equivalent is converted to special character)

Thank you !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java URL encoding of query string parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters)

Comment: show what you have tried. thanks

Comment: FYI, I believe the technical term for what you want is “Numeric Character Reference”.

Answer (score 3):

This can be simply achieved with `String.format()`. The representations are simply the character value as decimal, padded to 4 characters and wrapped in &#;

The only tricky part is deciding which characters are "special". Here I've assumed not digit, not whitespace and not alpha...

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
String input = "Foo bar ©™® baz";
for (char each : input.toCharArray()) {
    if (Character.isAlphabetic(each) || Character.isDigit(each) || Character.isWhitespace(each)) {
        output.append(each);
    } else {
        output.append(String.format("&#%04d;", (int) each));
    }
}
System.out.println(output.toString());
```

Comment: @Downvoter Please identify issues and I'll address them. Thank you :)

Comment: Seriously man, some people just down vote without any reason.

Comment: @adam - thank you. your answers looks apt for what I am looking for. I'll give it a try and let you know.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to fetch the integer value of the character as mentioned in [How do I get the decimal value of a unicode character in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766416/how-do-i-get-the-decimal-value-of-a-unicode-character-in-java).

As per Oracle Java [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

> char: The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has
>   a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or
>   65,535 inclusive).

Assuming your characters fall within the character range, you can just get the decimal equivalent of each character from your string.

```
    String text = "©™®";
    char[] cArr = text.toCharArray(); 
    for (char c : cArr)
    {
        int value = c; // get the decimal equivalent of the character
        String result = "& #" + value; // append to some format string
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

Output:

```
& #169
& #8482
& #174
```